# Trying to apply image fade in on click event to each image in an array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, onclick, click, fadein

Pretty new to jquery here. I'm trying to get an image to fade in when you click on a thumbnail. That in itself is pretty simple. The problem I have is that the thumbnails are contained in an array which is, in turn, taken from a database.

The function I've cobbled together to try to make this happen is as follows:

```
function display (array) {
$.each(array, function(i, val){
    var imageID=val[0], 
        imageURL=val[7];

'<img id="'+ imageID +'" src="images/'+ imageURL +'" width="100" height="123" />';

    $('#container').append(
        '<div id="'+array[i][0]+'" style="position: absolute;  left:'+array[i][8]+'px; top: '+array[i][9]+'px;"><img src=images/'+array[i][6]+' id=nav width=85 height=85></div>'
    );

    $("#"+array[i]).click(function () { 
            $("#"+imageID).fadeIn('slow', function  ()  {
                // animation complete
            });
      });
   });
}
```

for reference,
        array [i][0] refers to the image's ID (a number in the database table)
        array [i][6] is the location of the thumbnail
        array [i][7] is the location of the full sized image
        array [i][8] and array [i][9] should be self-explanatory, they're the coordinates on the page of the thumbnail.

I guess anyone with any knowledge of jquery will be able to see numerous flaws at first glance. I repeat though I'm pretty new to this so please be gentle with me(!)

I suspect that the problem lies in being able to identify the image that needs to be faded in - i'm not sure if

```
    '<img id="'+ array[i][0] +'" src="'+ array[i][6] +'" alt="" width="100" height="123" />';
```

is correct.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated though.

Thanks in advance
Stef

Answer (score 0):

Well if you insist on loading it all through jQuery, here's one way to do it, but I would generally advise against loading EVERYTHING through jQuery.

```
var content_images = '';
var content_thumbs = '';
$.each(array, function(i, val){

    var imageID=val[0], imageURL=val[7];

    content_images += '<img id="'+ imageID +'" src="images/'+ imageURL +'" width="100";height="123" />';
    content_thumbs += '<div onclick="showImage('+imageID+')" style="position: absolute;  left:'+array[i][8]+'px; top: '+array[i][9]+'px;"><img src=images/'+array[i][6]+' id=nav width=85 height=85></div>';
});

function showImage(id) {
    $('#'+id).fadeIn(slow, function(){} );
}

$('#imageContent').html(content_images);
$('#thumbContent').html(content_thumbs);
```

Try not to write so much CSS and HTML in javascript. Focus on JS giving you display logic, but leave the displaying itself to pure HTML. Makes everything easier to debug too. For instance, instead of having inline CSS on the thumbnails, why not give them a "thumb" class and write that CSS in normal CSS? There's no need to have JS write that same content out every single time. Etc...

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer. Just having me supper then will sit down and try and integrate it into my page. Thanks once again ;-)

Comment: Hmmm... sadly I can;t seem to get this working - I'm directly replacing the existing function with it but all that happens is that it knocks out all the images.

Comment: Don't directly replace it, you still have to change the IDs of the containers in question and add some display:none to all the actual images and whatnot. Directly copying it won't work, this was just a sample on how to do it. I'll whip up a fiddle later on and post here, maybe that'll be more helpful, you'll be able to see the source then as well